# Place a call from a View

Tags: android, android-activity, methods, view, phone-call

I have an app consisting of an Activity that displays a custom View that I created (a dialpad). The custom View has dials, an edittext used to display the number entered and a phonebutton that I want to use to place a call to the number the user has entered. Im trying to write the listener for that button. The listener must take the number from the edittext and place a call to it.

Ive found code that can be used to place calls and placed it in my Activity:

```
public void call(String number){
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
        startActivity(callIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

But the listener for the button is inside the custom View class. How can I call the call() method inside the Activity from the button listener in the View class?

****EDIT*********

It seems there was an easier way of doing it, I found this code that I could insert into the View class:

```
public void call(String number){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String dialNumber = "tel:";
        dialNumber = dialNumber + number;
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(dialNumber));
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Calling this method from the listener places the call.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea to call activity from within your view even if you're doing it through startActivity.  Problem is your View should be portable to any Activity you want to create.  By making direct calls or startActivity you're coupling it to that single use.  You'll never be able to reuse it anywhere but right there, plus using startActivity() isn't going to do what you think it will do.

Instead I'd create an interface and add a method to your view that allows the Activity to register itself as a listener for someone dialing a number.  For example:

```
public interface DialListener {
   public void onDialed( String number );
}
...
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements DialListener {
    public void onCreate( ... ) {
        YourCustomDialer dialer = (YourCustomerDialer)findViewById( R.id.dialer );
        dialer.setDialListener( this );
    }

    public void onDialed( String number ) {
        // do something here with dialed number
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Thank you for your thorough answer.

Comment: BTW what is your take on the solution I found?

Comment: Hi Fred, if chubbard answered your question don't forget to mark his answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: @S201 Chubbard did provide a great answer but in this case the issue turned out to be the starting of an Intent from within a View rather than calling methods in an Activity from within a View. Check my edited question and you will see what I mean. Im unsure as to whether I should mark Chubbards answer as "Accepted" since really we are talking about two different things.